# Create multiple files from a single file in R

Tags: r, file, split

I have a table that starts out looking like this:

```
test <- data.frame("Number" = c("123", "123", "123", "12", "12", "13"), "Value" = c(45, 46, 47, 33, 20, 45))
```

I want to create a seperate file for each unique "Number". So there would be 3 output files and I would like them to be called "123.txt" "12.txt" "13.txt". The 3 new tables would look like this:

```
test_123 <- data.frame("Number" = c("123", "123", "123"), "Value" = c(45, 46, 47))
test_12 <- data.frame("Number" = c("12", "12"), "Value" = c(33, 20))
test_13 <- data.frame("Number" = c("13"), "Value" = c(45))
```

I have no idea where to even begin with this, so your help is greatly appreciated :)!

Comment: I think you need `lst1 <- split(test, test$Number); names(lst1) <- paste0("test_", names(lst1)); lst2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: above has a typo, it's `list2env` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you:

```
#List
List <- split(test,test$Number)
#Names
namevec <- paste0(names(List),'.txt')
#Export
mapply(FUN = write.table,List,file=namevec)
```

Comment: thank you very much :)!

Comment: @Sarah Great it helped :)